# SQL: get rows "under" chosen row

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

I have a table like that

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | qwe |
| 2 | asd |
| 3 | sdf |
| 4 | xcv |
| 5 | try |

and I need to select all rows "under" chosen name (i.e. name = 'asd'), and after that sort it by 'id' and limit to 2, so I'm seeking a result like:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | sdf |
| 4 | xcv |

I tried to select it as SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE name < 'asd' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2

However, "name < 'asd'" only means the rows where name-value is less than 'asd', so I get nothing because there are no values less than 'asd'. In my case, I need to select all rows "under" 'asd' name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below

```
select id,name from table_name
where id > ( select id from table_name where name='asd')
order by id
limit 2
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=23b4ebc32e7def7ebd687f794a7c4d2e)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM TableName WHERE name = 'asd')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 2;
```